# Чтение-запись в Propertylist XCode

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте!
Для моей программы нужно сохранение данных, но я никак не могу понять как записывать в `plist`'ы.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Все о .plist'ах](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i)

Совсем малые объемы данных можете сохранять при помощи 
[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AccessingPreferenceValues/AccessingPreferenceValues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH3-SW1)

Если стоит задача хранить большие объемы данных - смотрите в сторону sqlite или Core Data